# What is document-tree child browsing context in HTML specification?

Tags: html

The term of **document-tree child browsing context** is defined by the spec [in the following way](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#document-tree-child-browsing-context):

> A browsing context child is a **document-tree child browsing context**
> of parent if child is a child browsing context and child's container
> is in a document tree.

In the other hand, **in a document tree** [means](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#in-a-document-tree)

> An element is **in a document tree** if its root is a document.

So the latter concept is concerned with DOM tree and its elements. Is it accurate to say that child's container (i.e. its parent), which is *a broswing context*, is a DOM element (node) and it is in a node tree? It is said, a browsing context is an environment in which Document objects are presented to the user, therefore, to the best of knowledge, it can't be thought of as a node element itself.

How it is possible to understand the idea of **document-tree child browsing context**? I need some example to chew it up.